# Некорректный вывод данных из БД, в чем проблема?

Tags: php, mysqli

Должен быть простой вывод всех значений по id из таблицы с дальнейшей постраничной разбивкой, но получается какая-то ерунда, аля выводятся только нечётные. Что можете сказать? Сильно не пинайте, пожалуйста.

```
require_once '/include/connection.php';
 $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
     exit();
    }
    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
    $quantity = 3;
    $limit = 3;
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    if(!is_numeric($page)) $page=1;
    if ($page<1) $page=1;
    $result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM videos");
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
    $pages = $num/$quantity;
    $pages = ceil($pages);
    $pages++;
    if ($page>$pages) $page = 1;
    if (!isset($list)) $list=0;
    $list=--$page*$quantity;
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM videos
     LIMIT $quantity OFFSET $list");
    $num_result = mysqli_num_rows($result)


<? for ($i = 0; $i<$num_result; $i++) {
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 print '<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6 mb-4">

 <!--Card-->
 <div class="card">

 <!--Card image-->
 <div class="view overlay">
 <img src="/1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="">
 <a href="'.$row->url.'">

 <div class="mask rgba-white-slight waves-effect waves-light"></div>
 </a>
 '.$result->id.'
 </div>

 </div>
 <!--/.Card-->

 </div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Почти 20 лет прошло от 21 века, а на пхп все так же пишут, как будто сейчас 1990-е. Просто удивительно, насколько живучи старые учебники. Вот как можно из всего многообразия учебных материалов наткнуться на такой, который был написан в прошлом веке?

Comment: У вас в запросах не указан ORDER BY, а следовательно БД возвращает строки в том порядке как ей захочется. Она имеет полное право вернуть сначала нечетные. Ну и код надо конечно пересматривать. Особенно определение количества записей в таблице с помощью mysqli_num_rows да еще при выборке `*`, т.е. всех столбцов. Вы понимаете что ради подсчета количества вы фактически запрашиваете у БД всю таблицу, целиком скачиваете ее в буфера php и потом считаете. Изучайте sql, например количество можно получить `select count(*) from videos` и из БД в php придет только одна цифра, а не все данные

Comment: Помимо того, что изучают старый материал, так самый прикол еще в том, что это делают абсолютно все кто начинает))) Откуда вы беретесь? Там секта какая та?

Comment: Ну так дай ссылки на свежие и верные материалы, я тоже умею в комментах кукарекaть.